# Delay based on events

Tags: .net, events, delay

I have the following class which publishes a message on aws sns queues "TryRestart()":

```
internal class SmsReceptionTestRunner : ITestRunner<ConfigurationViaSmsAttempt>
{
    private readonly CommunicationClient _communicationClient;

    public SmsReceptionTestRunner(CommunicationClient communicationClient)
    {
        _communicationClient = communicationClient;
    }

    public Test Execute(ConfigurationViaSmsAttempt MessageType)
    {
        // publish
        _communicationClient.ConfigurationService.TryRestart(MessageType.Imei);

        // wait five minutes ...    

        return new Test("6", "", false, MessageType.TargetApn, MessageType.TargetApn);
    }
}
```

A separate handler class takes care of the answer whenever it's published on the queues - typically this takes around five minutes - `await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));`. After the 5 min. if no messages has been handled I saved a new Test set to false.:

```
public class RestartViaSmsAttemptHandler : IHandler<RestartViaSmsAttempt>
{
    private readonly IRepository<Test> _TestRepository;

    public RestartViaSmsAttemptHandler(IRepository<Test> TestRepository)
    {
        _TestRepository = TestRepository;
    }

    public bool Handle(RestartViaSmsAttempt message)
    {
        var test = new Test("6", message.Imei, true, "", "");
        _TestRepository.Save(test);
        return true;
    }
}
```

I want to place a mechanism to prevent the `// wait five minutes` bit to run only if my Handler gets a message back from the queues.

Basically, I'm asking to something to reboot and after 5 minutes, if there's no answer, I know something went wrong.

Comment: The problem statement is not clear. Do you want to abort the 5min wait early if a message arrives? Did you try anything yet?

Comment: I've tried by adding 'await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));' then check if the test was saved but I don't like that solution. I guess I'd have to abort the 5 minutes somehow. I'm looking for a better design here

Answer (score 0):

You can abort a wait early like this:

```
await Task.WhenAll(someTask, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
```

When `someTask` becomes completed the wait ends. You can produce a task to complete at will using `TaskCompletionSource`.

So if you receive a reply you complete the task and end the wait.

Are you sure you need message queues? You are basically running a synchronous call over a message queue. Maybe an normal web service call is all you need.

Comment: The communication with the device that is restarted is made via aws sns. There's no task to complete, only an approximate response time for the device to answer of five minutes. This answer is managed by the handler.

Comment: `I guess I'd have to abort the 5 minutes somehow.` I told you how to do that. You create the task *yourself* and complete it whenever you want to abort the wait. Does that work for you?

Comment: In particular I'm confused by you stating that there is no task when my entire answer is centered around creating one.